# AndroidBitmap_lockPixels fails with ANDROID_BITMAP_RESULT_ALLOCATION_FAILED

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, bytebuffer

I have my own native implementation for `getByteBuffer` in Android, so that I can get a wrapper around the bitmap array for sending the correct pointers to OpenGL. This implementation works fine, but in some random cases and at random times, I get a failure on being unable to lock the bitmap pixels. I debugged to find out that the error comes from `ANDROID_BITMAP_RESULT_ALLOCATION_FAILED` in `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels`.

Here is how I send the pointers to OpenGL:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      GLES20.glTexImage2D(
          GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i,
          0,
          COLOR_FORMAT,
          sideLength,
          sideLength,
          0,
          COLOR_FORMAT,
          GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
          Bitmaps.getByteBuffer(mBitmap, (bitmapByteCount / 6) * i, bitmapByteCount / 6));
    }
```

And here is my native implementation for `getByteBuffer`:

```
static jobject Bitmaps_getByteBuffer(
  JNIEnv* env,
  jclass clazz,
  jobject bitmap,
  jlong offset,
  jlong size) {
  UNUSED(clazz);
  void* pixelPtr;
  AndroidBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;

  int rc = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &bitmapInfo);
  if (rc != ANDROID_BITMAP_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
    safe_throw_exception(env, "Failed to get Bitmap info");
    return NULL;
  }

  if (bitmapInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
    safe_throw_exception(env, "Unexpected bitmap format");
    return NULL;
  }

  jlong arrayLength = bitmapInfo.width * bitmapInfo.height * 4;
  if (offset < 0 || size < 0 || offset > arrayLength || arrayLength - offset < size) {
    safe_throw_exception(env, "Index out of bounds");
    return NULL;
  }

  rc = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixelPtr);
  if (rc != ANDROID_BITMAP_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
    safe_throw_exception(env, "Failed to lock Bitmap pixels");
    return NULL;
  }

  pixelPtr = (void*) ((uint8_t*) pixelPtr + offset);
  return (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, pixelPtr, size);
}
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: the obvious answer is that, you're running out of memory :0.

Comment: No, I do not think so. It happens at random times, and when I put this in a try-catch, it just works fine. So yeah, it is not related to running out of memory.